# What are the difference between django-compressor and django-sass processor?

Tags: python, django, sass, django-compressor

I'm using django compressor, to compress JS and CSS. As the introduction about django compressor says:"Django Compressor processes, combines and minifies linked and inline Javascript or CSS in a Django template into cacheable static files."

Looks like the same goal of django-sass-processor. The problem when I use django-compressor is that during the development, my application is slow (more than 2 second to render a page that has no DB access in the view and doesn't process anything). Is that normal?

I thought to speed up the apps, using the sass processor that checks the timestamp and compile the sass file only if there's some change (is this the purpose of the tool right?).

By the way, I have a bit of confusion, can you explain me what are and how to use it?

## Edit 1:

When I request the index ( http://localhost:8000/) for example, the following resources are requested:

```
[21/Aug/2016 16:09:43] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 2346
[21/Aug/2016 16:09:43] "GET /static/CACHE/css/bootstrap.min.35ea483046e0.css HTTP/1.1" 200 145948
[21/Aug/2016 16:09:43] "GET /static/CACHE/css/bitdepot.762c234abcad.css HTTP/1.1" 200 5359
[21/Aug/2016 16:09:43] "GET /static/CACHE/css/core.d64c40e32055.css HTTP/1.1" 200 6517
```

On each request, the files in CACHE changes, even if I don't touch it. I think the app is slower cause of it.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used django befor however the SASS Processor will process SASS code which is kinda like advanced/modified CSS